# file_get_contents with relative path

Tags: php

I have the following directory structure.

```
/var/www/base/controller/detail.php
/var/www/base/validate/edit.json
/var/www/html
```

Within `/var/www/base/controller/detail.php`, how do I use `file_get_contents()` with a relative path to read `/var/www/base/validate/edit.json`?  I've tried the following:

```
//failed to open stream: No such file or directory (error no: 2)
$json=file_get_contents('detail.php');

//No error, but I don't want this file and was just testing
$json=file_get_contents('detail.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

//failed to open stream: No such file or directory (error no: 2)
$json=file_get_contents('./validate/edit.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
//failed to open stream: No such file or directory (error no: 2)
$json=file_get_contents('../validate/edit.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
//failed to open stream: No such file or directory (error no: 2)
$json=file_get_contents('././validate/edit.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
//failed to open stream: No such file or directory (error no: 2)
$json=file_get_contents('../../validate/edit.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

//This works, but I want to use a relative path
$json=file_get_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/validate/edit.json');
```

Comment: The first two read `detail.php`, not `edit.json`.

Comment: @GolezTrol.  Yes, this was just for testing purposes.

Comment: It's better to not use relative directories, but use an absolute path based on, for instance, `__DIR__`, `__FILE__`, a setting or other server configuration. See also: [Resolving PHP Relative Path Problem](http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/) for the How and the Why.

Comment: @GolezTrol  I typically do use absolute paths (because of stuff like this!), but the documentation says I could use a relative path.  Why isn't it working?

Comment: @GolezTrol  Ah, the reason.  Made my head hurt a bit, but your attached link shows the "How and the Why".

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../validate/edit.json');
```

[`__DIR__`](https://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is a useful magic constant.

For reasons why, see http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/.

> When a PHP file includes another PHP file which itself includes yet another file — all being in separate directories — using relative paths to include them may raise a problem.
>
> PHP will often report that it is unable to find the third file, but why?
>    Well the answer lies in the fact that when including files in PHP the interpreter tries to find the file in the current working directory.
>
> In other words, if you run the script in a directory called A and you include a script that is found in directory B, then the relative path will be resolved relative to A when executing a script found in directory B.
>
> So, if the script inside directory B includes another file that is in a different directory, the path will still be calculated relative to A not relative to B as you might expect.

Comment: I haven't tried but I am sure it will work since `__FILE__` worked.  Question is how to do so with relative paths, however.

Comment: A very useful constant, but not much different from using `dirname()`.

Comment: @user1032531 ah yep fair point! Perhaps check out [`realpath()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

Comment: Yes, does in fact work, and I agree it is a bit more concise than `dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/validate/edit.json'` and plan on doing exactly as you show (+1), but it doesn't answer the question why `file_get_contents` doesn't work with relative paths.

Answer (score 7):

try using this

```
$json = file_get_contents("/path/to/your/file/edit.json", true);
```

As of PHP 5 the FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH constant can be used to trigger include path search. This is not possible if strict typing is enabled since FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH is an int. Use TRUE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of cause there is the possibility to use the include_path parameter. Set this parameter to '1' then a search for the file in the include_path (in php.ini.) will be done. You have to do editing in the php.ini!

When using $json=file_get_contents('detail.php'); a call is done from a php file.
Use file_get_contents('detail.php'); to have the detail.php get executed. the file have to be in the root directory (same as the calling php file in which the file_get_contents() is situated). If detail.php is in a subdirectory i can not see any workaround than using the include_path parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to do the opposite first to find out:

```php
file_put_contents('FINDME', 'smth');
exit();
$json=file_get_contents('detail.php');
...
```

Then run something like this from your terminal on *nix system (or search for a file named `FINDME` using GUI on Windows)

```
find <root-dir-of-the-project> -name 'FINDME'
```

The command will output something like this:

```
<root-dir-of-the-project>/<directories>/FINDME
```

**Now you know the root dir** (from which the relative path is being taken) for the file where you are attempting to read the other files and you can construct the relative path easily