# PHP get_file_path returning false

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read in a file contents as follows, but I'm getting false back.

I looked at [get_file_contents returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798629/file-get-contents-with-relative-path) but their solution isn't working.

```
$fileName = "/opt/IB/cust/HW/junk/Exclude_E7.csv";
$hw= "EPHRPH1";
print "checking for " . $hw. "\n";
if(strlen($hw)>6)
{
    //look for hw in file
    $contents = file_get_contents($fileName);
    var_dump($contents);
}
```

prints

```
checking for EPHRPH1
bool(false)
```

When I list the file at the command line, it finds it.  I've tried this with exec and grep, and grep can't find the file or dir with the full path.  I looked at the file, and it has 777 permissions, and the same user as I'm running the script with.

I tried this as well, like at the link, but it's returning false as well.

```
$contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . $fileName);
```

Any idea why it's not finding/reading the file or how to get the file contents read into a string? My ultimate goal is to look for $hw in the file contents. I'm debugging why this doesn't work, and found out it's not finding the file:

```
$result = strpos(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . $fileName),$hw);
```

Comment: have you checked the server's error logs? any clue there?

Comment: You can test with `file_exists($fileName)` if your path is correct.

Comment: Does the account your web server is running under have access to that folder

Comment: It's not a web page, it's just a php script.

Comment: Then does the account you are running under have access?

Comment: If you get `false`, you should also get a warning with the actual error message. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the top of your file. It could be that the user you have doesn't have read access to one or more folders above the file. If a folder have, for example, `700` with another user and you put a file inside that, you won't be able to read it even if that file has `777` and you are the owner.

Comment: yes, the account I am running under owns the file.

Comment: /opt is drwxr-xr-x, IB has drwxr-xr-x, cust has drwxrwxr-x, but I'm not the owner of those.  The HW and junk dirs I own and are 777.

Comment: I added the suggesting logging changes, and when I try to run it, the error messages are: for the Exclude file... failed to open stream: No such file or directory, and it points to line 253, which is $contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . $fileName);

Comment: You are getting "No such file or directory" because `__DIR__` does not include a trailing slash - if your script is in /tmp/test/index.php, `echo __DIR__` will return `/tmp/test`. So when you do `__DIR__ . $fileName`, the file will not exist.

Try `__DIR__ . '/' . $fileName` instead, you need to add that slash back.

Comment: I tried adding the slash @ZachBloomquist and I still get the same error message. What I'm noticing now, though, is it's putting the dir path twice. " file_get_contents(/opt/IBM/custom/HW//opt/IBM/custom/HW/junk/Exclude_E7.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/IBM/custom/HW/poll_hw.php on line 253"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with the error message I got by turning on logging as suggested above, and changed it to this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . "junk/Exclude_E7.csv");
```

and it worked.  Thanks for the help!