# file_put_contents failed to open stream even though folder is there

Tags: php, laravel

This is really simple and yet I am really struggling.

So I am downloading a file from a url and trying to save it into a folder like this:

```
file_put_contents('../uploads/' . $newFilename, fopen('http:' . $process->output->url, 'r'));
```

When I run that I get this error: `message: "file_put_contents(../uploads/20181028203041.mp3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"`

When I run this line:

```
file_put_contents($newFilename, fopen('http:' . $process->output->url, 'r'));
```

The file drops nicely into my public folder. I do have an uploads folder, but this just isn't working. What silly mistake have I made here.

Proof of the folder:
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798629/file-get-contents-with-relative-path

Comment: That question hasn't solved the problem so I disagree

Comment: Have you tried using `__DIR__`?

Comment: I have yes,  this drops me into my controllers folder which is no good

Comment: Point being is that you can solve your problem by using absolute paths. One way is to prepend `__DIR__` and navigate from there, or you prepend a config variable that points to a specific location. Both has pros and cons.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but at the end of the day I know about and had tried `__DIR__` and needed a better solution. Artyom provided what I was looking for, you just said look elsewhere and haven't really helped constructively

Comment: No need to get defensive. Comments on Stack Overflow are there for providing hints or clarifying on the issue, not providing answers to the question. I’m glad to hear that your issue is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can successfully save to public in this way, than try to change `'../uploads/'` to `uploads/`.
In case of `../uploads/` you are trying to save to `beatpub/uploads` folder.

Comment: I actually solved by adding `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of the `../` but this would have worked as well I think